# WPF formatting by Class instead of property?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to apply formatting to a WPF control by class type. Say I have a class with five subclasses and I want to give a different color based on the subclass that is initiated. Can I bind to a class and differentiate by subclass type or do I have to set a subclass specific property to bind to?

Currently I have a string property in each subclass which I bind to and I use a converter to return the right brush. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way by looking at the class type.

Comment: It should be pretty simple to add a virtual get-only property to the base class and bind to it.  Otherwise you'll probably need to use custom code in the control that uses reflection.

Comment: Please see [this article](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Some extra information added

Comment: An attribute can be used, as described below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a ContentControl to your object create a different DataTemplate for each subclass. Let's assume the control you want to show is a Button, then it would be something like this.

```
<ContentControl Content={Binding ...}>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:Subclass1}>
            <Button Background="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:Subclass2}>
            <Button Background="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        ...
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

It might seem a bit of a heavy solution for your situation perhaps, but this construction comes in handy very often!

Answer (score 0):

You may bind color property to instance and write a converter which will return different Brush for different type:

```
Background={Binding Converter={c:InstanceToColorConverter}},
```

in InstanceToColorConverter's Convert method if statements cascade may be implemented

```
if(value is A)return new SomeBrush();else 
   if(value is B)return new AntoherBrush();
```

You may also create class `Attribute` which stores prefered brush color and detect it value in Convert method like:

```
value.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false).First(x=>x is ColorAttribute).Color
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to design DataTemplates for each subclass in XAML. But yes, you can also bind to the subclass type.

In your base, provide the .Net type:

```
public Type MyType
    {
        get
        {
            return GetType();
        }
    }
```

In your Xaml, trigger on MyType, subclasses will inherit it:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyType}" Value="{x:Type myNamespace:MySubClass1}">
    <Setter ../>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyType}" Value="{x:Type myNamespace:MySubClass2}">
    <Setter ../>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following solution:

```
<Grid Background = "{Binding Converter={StaticResource Myconverter} />
```

this passes my class object using the datacontext the grid resides in.

I then use a converter to check for class type and return the corresponding colorbrush.

Comment: This is a working solution. I did that too! But nowadays I try to avoid any Type-dependencies in converters. Converter belong to the XAML and should be re-usable for other components (especially in large projects, e.g. think of the BooleanToVisibilityConverter).